# How can I remove the commas between a list's elements?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

Does anyone know how to remove the comma's in this list?

```
[4.1755139724695871, -2.6367224815727237, 2.3407722739111092, 0.36546242292367692]
```

It has to be like this:

```
[ 4.17551397 -2.63672248  2.34077227  0.36546242]
```

I used this code:

```
import numpy as np
def ontbinding(A, x):
    N, N = A.shape
    e = np.linalg.eig(A)
    eigenvector = e[1]
    return [np.dot(x.T,(eigenvector[:,i]).T)[0] for i in range(N)]
```

And the following array and list were given.

```
A = np.array([[  0.,   0.,   5.,  -2.],
 [  0.,  -4.,   7.,   4.],
 [  5.,   7.,  18.,   3.],
 [ -2.,   4.,   3.,   0.]])
x = np.array([[1.], [2.], [3.], [4.]])
```

Comment: What exactly do you have to compute, because I can't really see what you're doing wrong with the given code?

Comment: The example output at the top seems to be the default string representation of an array. To change the representation, it is probably the fastest to write your own ToString function.

Comment: Commas are part of the printed representation, not part of the actual data structure. Your data structure has no commas in it. If you don't want to print commas, you need to change how you're printing your data, not how it's stored.

Comment: Check out [an answer to a similar (duplicate?) question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13861407/100770) Just use a space for your delimiter instead of a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code must give you the right answer.

```
 import numpy as np
    def ontbinding(A, x):
        N, N = A.shape
        e = np.linalg.eig(A)
        eigenvector = e[1]
        return np.array([np.dot(x.T,(eigenvector[:,i]).T)[0] for i in range(N)])
```

Just keep in mind that when you use a comprehension, you will automatically receive a list. When you want to change that list into an array just use:

```
np.array(list)
```

Answer (score 4):

The *list*, per se, has no commas.  That's only the print image (generated with `str` or `__repr__`) that inserts the commas as the default output rendering.  What you can do with such an object is to make the image explicitly, remove the commas, and print that.

```
list_str = str(list).replace(',', '')
print list_str
```

Is that what you need?

Answer (score 2):

You define `A` and `x` as arrays; their print representation does not have commas.  Your input is in the form of lists, which requires commas.

```
In [39]: A
Out[39]: 
array([[  0.,   0.,   5.,  -2.],
       [  0.,  -4.,   7.,   4.],
       [  5.,   7.,  18.,   3.],
       [ -2.,   4.,   3.,   0.]])
In [40]: x
Out[40]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 2.],
       [ 3.],
       [ 4.]])
In [41]: print(A)
[[  0.   0.   5.  -2.]
 [  0.  -4.   7.   4.]
 [  5.   7.  18.   3.]
 [ -2.   4.   3.   0.]]
In [42]: print(x)
[[ 1.]
 [ 2.]
 [ 3.]
 [ 4.]]
```

Your function returns a list, the result of list comprehension, `[... for i in range(N)]`.

```
In [44]: y = ontbinding(A,x)
In [45]: y
Out[45]: 
[4.1755139724695871,
 -2.6367224815727233,
 2.3407722739111088,
 0.36546242292367614]
```

You could turn that into an array:

```
In [46]: np.array(y)
Out[46]: array([ 4.17551397, -2.63672248,  2.34077227,  0.36546242])
In [47]: print(np.array(y))
[ 4.17551397 -2.63672248  2.34077227  0.36546242]
```

Comment: This should be considered as the better answer.